# Image scaling issues (size reduction quality loss)

Tags: html, css, image, photoshop

I'm trying to make the images on my website smaller in their px dimensions, but I'm having issues with quality loss when I resize them in Photoshop (I first tried “Bicubic Sharper,” then all other resampling options, but they all came out blurry).
When I let the browser do the scaling (by stating the smaller width in my CSS), they come out perfectly sharp. How can that happen?
I would like to reduce my original images though. How can I make them smaller without quality loss? (I have Photoshop and Illustrator)

Comment: this is a question for [**graphicdesign.stackexchange.com**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh thank you! I'll post it there...

Answer (score 0):

If you have photoshop then keep the `automatic` resampling options while resizing image/photos (`alt⌥ + cmd⌘ + I`) it should perfectly do the job for this type of work.

If you have problems with photoshop resizing (even when set up on automatic) then you can try to resize the photos in some online editors like `picmonkey` and see what will happen).